# Meteor.js: Collection.insert works on server but not client

Tags: meteor

Trying to understand CRUD in Meteor & have a fundamental problem, which is that when I remove auto publish and use explicit pub/sub, collection inserts from the client update the server but not the client collection.

The result is that while the field values are obtained properly, the insert fails on the client side. On the server side, the record is inserted correctly.

**$ meteor remove autopublish**

Create HTML form file (it's valid and functions as expected), then:

**File /server/publish.js:**

```
Meteor.publish('todos'), function() {
    return Todos.find();
}
```

**File /lib/collections.js:**

```
Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

**File /client/subscribe.js:**

```
Meteor.subscribe('todos');
```

**File /client/todos.js:**

```
Template.todosList.helpers({
    todosList: function() {
        return Todos.find();
    },
  });

Template.todoNew.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var theRecord = {
            description: $(event.target).find('[id=description]').val(),
            priority: $(event.target).find('[id=priority]').val()
        };
        // Display correct field values, so form data is OK
        console.log('Attemping to insert: ' + theRecord.description);
        Todos.insert(theRecord, function(error) {
            // This error always occurs
            console.log('error inserting: ' + theRecord.description);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write to a collection from the client you will need an [allow](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) rule. Put something like this under `/server`:

```js
Meteor.publish('todos', function() {
  return Todos.find();
});

Todos.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    // a todo must have a description and a priority
    return (doc.description && doc.priority);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much--I still can't get it to work. I have tried a couple of different versions and they result in runtime errors like this:  **Exception while invoking method '/todos/insert' TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null**

Here are my attempts:
**File /server/publish.hs:**
`
    Todos.allow({
      insert: function (userId, doc) {
        return (doc.description && doc.priority);
      }
    });
`
And:
**File /server/publish.hs:**

`   Todos.allow({
     insert: function (theRecord) {
       return (theRecord.description && theRecord.priority);
     }
   });

Comment: @tomcam, the first parameter is the user's id (or `null`, if the user isn't signed in), the second parameter stores the document.

Comment: Thought so, @peppe-l-g, and thanks for the reply! Hence my second version, which also doesn't work. I have purposely removed autopublish while **not** adding accounts-ui. It seems to me that pub/sub technically would have nothing to do with accounts-ui, though of course practically speaking it should in any worthwhile app. 

Am I wrong? Do I always have to add accounts-ui when I remove autopublish?

Comment: `accounts-ui` and `autopublish` can be installed independently of one another. I updated the answer. Your errors indicate that `doc` is `undefined` which I didn't think was possible. Alternatively you can try just returning `true` from the function (though then your schema isn't being checked). If all of that still doesn't work, please put your code on [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/) or in a github repo that I can look at.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidWeldon. I didn't know about Meteorpad. I've put it up at (http://meteorpad.com/pad/aNfQ9gsT5QjT3BEbo/).

Comment: It was an unrelated issue. The syntax of your publisher was wrong. I updated the answer to include both the publisher and the allow rule.

Comment: Doh! Apparently I am now regressing in Javascript too. However, the problem remains. I'm pretty sure I have now officially overstayed my welcome, but I'm getting a [Collection name, Todos in this case] not defined ReferenceError. Refactored code at (http://meteorpad.com/pad/tevTy7FbG7CJ4cnfY/todoozie). Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: Yeah that's actually a problem with meteorpad (sort of). `/common.js` isn't forced to run before the rest of the code so the collection definition isn't properly ordered. The correct solution is to put your collection definitions under `/lib` but that isn't available on meteorpad. That's what I did when when I tested your code locally, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks to @DavidWeldon and a little tweaking of the code it's now working! See http://meteorpad.com/pad/tevTy7FbG7CJ4cnfY/todoozie